# How to combine SVG linear gradient and <rect> with feDisplacementMap and apply it to div element?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, svg-filters

I have a **react** project, and I want to implement some **SVG filter**, but I'm having a problem now, the filter doesn't work. It Looks like there is some problem with the way I structure the SVG code block. It works when I use Data URI. The reason why **I don't use Data URI** is because I want to create some **animations**, it's kind of hard for me to implement those using Data URI, so I go back to standard svg template. Any Idea Where I did wrong ?

**Here is the code:**

```
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        ref={svgRef}
        width="1000"
        height="200"
        style={{
          width: '1000px',
          display: 'block',
          // zIndex: '10',
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 0,
        }}
      >
        <defs>
          <linearGradient
            id="grad1"
            x1="0%"
            y1="11%"
            x2="0%"
            y2="32%"
          >
            <stop
              offset="0%"
              style={{ stopColor: 'rgb(255,0,0)', stopOpacity: '1' }}
            />
            <stop
              offset="100%"
              style={{ stopColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)', stopOpacity: '1' }}
            />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <rect id="rectangle" width="1000" height="100" fill="url(#grad1)" />
        <filter id="f" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <feImage
            ref={feImageRef}
            result="pict2"
            xlinkHref="#rectangle"
          ></feImage>

          <feDisplacementMap
            rotate={rotate}
            scale={scale}
            xChannelSelector="R"
            yChannelSelector="R"
            in2="pict2"
            in="SourceGraphic"
          />
        </filter>
      </svg>
```

Comment: I'm not deeply familiar with react, but rotate isn't a property supported inside feDisplacementMap; and ref isn't a supported property inside feImage. (And sometimes if you don't size your feImage - sometimes it causes problems). Fragment identifiers like #rectangle aren't supported as an feImage input in Firefox.